# React Native Array Map Error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I seem to be having an issue with a React Native app I am building. I am passing an array of objects as a prop to a component and trying to map through the array. Here is a sample of the array:

```
[{"title":"test"},{"title":"test"},{"title":"test"}]
```

I can output the entire array, however if I try to map through the array I get this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.props.history_data.map')
```

Here is my container render function:

```
render() {
return (
  <View>
    <Text>
      {this.props.history_data.map(route => {
          return (
            <Text key={route.title}>{route.title}</Text>
          );
        })
      }
    </Text>
  </View>
);
}
```

Been banging my head on the desk for too long. Time to ask for help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you do `console.log(this.props.history_data)`  just before `return(` and add it here?

Comment: Here is the result: [{"title":"test"},{"title":"test"},{"title":"test"}]

Comment: You may need parentheses around route, so it would look like `this.props.history_data.map((route) => {`

Comment: @BlakeSteel You don't need parens there. If there is only one argument, you don't need them.

Comment: can you post `console.log(typeof this.props.history_data)`

Comment: It returns undefined.

Comment: really strange though, first time it is an array, second it is undefined. Can you post the whole component then? Now I think the proble is in delay or something,not sure though

Comment: I think it is a timing issue too. The data for this component is fetched asynchronously from AsyncStorage and then I use setState to pass the data to the component as a prop. It seems like that component isn't updating after I call setState or something...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your issue. But git it a shot. If `this.props.history_data` is ever `undefined` when your component renders, you'll get an error since you're calling `.map` on `undefined`, which obviously has no `.map` method. Try doing a null check?

```
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>
                {this.props.history_data && this.props.history_data.length ?
                    this.props.history_data.map(route => {
                        return (
                            <Text key={route.title}>{route.title}</Text>
                        );
                    }) : null // either set as null or render another component when it's undefined or of zero length
                }

            </Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried a similar approach by adding this at the beginning of the render function: if (!this.props.history_data.isArray()) {
      return <Text>Not an array</Text>;
    } but I still get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried simplifying it? Like dumbing the array down to an array of strings just to see if you can get _any_ `.map` working? I dunno. I don't see anything obvious from the code you posted.

Comment: Yes. If I hard-code the array it works fine: {[{"title":"test"},{"title":"test"},{"title":"test"}].map(route => {

Comment: That sure sounds like an `undefined` issue. What does your log say the very first time? Log it like `console.log('history_data', history_data)`. I would expect it to show up once with `undefined` before it shows up later with the data you expect.

Comment: Yeah it kept saying "undefined" even after calling setState in the parent component. I did find a solution though. See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
render() {
  let routes = this.props.history_data.map(route => {
                    return (
                        <Text key={route.title}>{route.title}</Text>
                    );
                })
  return (
    <View>
        <Text>
            {routes}
        </Text>
    </View>
);
```

}

Comment: @BWDesign so the problem is not in `history_data` itself, the problem is somewhere in `Text` or in keys of objects. You sure all array elements have 'title' key?

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. If I replace the prop with a hard-coded array the map works fine: {[{"title":"test"},{"title":"test"},{"title":"test"}].map(route => {

Answer (score 0):

I never did figure out exactly why my code wasn't working. I think it was some kind of timing issue as the data being passed as a prop was being loaded asynchronously from AsyncStorage by the parent component and then passed to the child component using setState.

I ended up rewiring the component to fetch the data directly from AsyncStorage instead of receiving it as a prop from the parent component.

Thank you all for helping me think through this!

Answer (score -1):

not really sure, but you might try this

```
{this.props.history_data.map( 
  (route) => { 
     return ( <Text key={route.title}>{route.title}</Text> ); 
   })
}
```

`router =>` should be `(router) =>`

Comment: Try defining an arrow function in your console passing the argument without parentheses. See what happens. Also, check out the third and fourth comments under the OP.